# Proper way to ajaxify links?

Tags: 7, ajax

According to a [comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7#comment-14324) on Drupal's AJAX framework it should be possible to define a link as a render array which Drupal then would turn into an ajaxified link. As far as I understand it, the essential part of this is :

```
$link = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => t('something'),
  '#href' => 'some/path',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'some_callback_function',
    'wrapper' => 'ajax-response-goes-here',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
```

However, I'm not quite certain which url the client would use to actually invoke the AJAX request? I know forms use 'system/ajax' to access callback methods from there, but what about this case?

If anyone would have the chance to shed a little light on how to properly ajaxify links, I'd be very greatful!

Comment: Have a look at the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples); it has an ajax_example module that walks you through how to do this. There's an extensive explanation and code examples in the ajax_example_misc.inc file

Comment: @Clive,  thanks for disappeared but awesome link to http://www.slideshare.net/merlinofchaos/drupal-7-advanced-ajax

Comment: @kalabro Wow you're quick that was only there for about 20 seconds! I thought the examples module link was a bit more appropriate as it's got a great example for what the OP is after. It is an awesome slideshow though, glad I came across it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be rather suspicious about the '#ajax' way. Try to have a look here : http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example_misc.inc/function/ajax_example_render_link/7

#### What they say :

- include the ajax.js
- add use-ajax class
- implement ajax callback under the link your link directs to

what should be done after the callback executes can be set by the ajax commands.

Comment: But the very next function in the file ([`ajax_example_render_link_ra()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_misc.inc/function/ajax_example_render_link_ra/7)) shows how to do it with a render array. ;)

Comment: I used same but it didn't work for me. :( Any solution?